# Why doesn't my mod_security catch / log anything?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, mod-security

I installed mod_security on my Ubuntu GNU/Linux server but when I send some simple requests to the web server that should match even the simplest rules, I fail to see any alerts or any log files that were supposed to exist in /var/log/apache2. What am I missing?

Before proceeding further here's my system details:

```
$ apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep secu
Syntax OK
 security2_module (shared)

$ sudo lsof | grep mod_security
apache2   12773        root  mem       REG      202,0   268828      50225 /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_security2.so
apache2   15287    www-data  mem       REG      202,0   268828      50225 /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_security2.so
apache2   15288    www-data  mem       REG      202,0   268828      50225 /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_security2.so
...
```

And here is the relevant part from my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
      # Basic configuration options
      SecRuleEngine On
      SecRequestBodyAccess On
      SecResponseBodyAccess Off

      # Handling of file uploads
      # TODO Choose a folder private to Apache.
      # SecUploadDir /opt/apache-frontend/tmp/
      SecUploadKeepFiles Off

      # Debug log
      SecDebugLog /var/log/apache2/modsec_debug.log
      SecDebugLogLevel 3

      # Serial audit log
      SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly
      SecAuditLogRelevantStatus ^5
      SecAuditLogParts ABIFHZ
      SecAuditLogType Serial
      SecAuditLog /var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log

      # Maximum request body size we will
      # accept for buffering
      SecRequestBodyLimit 131072

      # Store up to 128 KB in memory 
      SecRequestBodyInMemoryLimit 131072
      # Buffer response bodies of up to # 512 KB in length 
      SecResponseBodyLimit 524288

      # Configure default blocking policy
      # see ModSecurity Handbook, p. 175
      #
      #SecDefaultAction "phase:1,log,auditlog,pass"

      Include /etc/apache2/modsecurity-crs_2.0.6/*.conf
      Include /etc/apache2/modsecurity-crs_2.0.6/base_rules/*.conf  

      SecFilter "/bin/"
      SecFilter "/cgi-bin" "deny,log,status:500"


      # By default log and deny suspicious requests
      # with HTTP status 500
      SecFilterDefaultAction "deny,log,status:500"
</IfModule>
```

So I expect that if I try to visit my web site and send a request that matches one of the filters I declared above using SecFilter or anything that matches the base rules, etc. then I should see something in those files:

```
/var/log/apache2/modsec_debug.log
/var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log
```

right?

However those files do not exist no matter what I try:

```
http://www.myserver.com/cgi-bin
http://www.myserver.com/index.html?q=/cgi-bin
http://www.myserver.com/bin
http://www.myserver.com/index.html?q=/bin
http://www.myserver.com/index.html?q=/bin/
```

Why can't I see any modsec_debug.log or modsec_audit.log in /var/log/apache2 ? I also don't get status 500 from the server. All I can see from the requests above is a few entries in the error.log file in /var/log/apache2 stating that the files I requested were not found but no alerts produced by mod_security.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shame on me! I've put the mod-security config directives **before** (and not after) the:

```
# Include module configuration:
Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.load
Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.conf
```

so mod-security module was not loaded actually! Now that I placed the mod-security directives **below** them, mod-security is loaded and it logs to the relevant files. Problem solved.

Comment: you can mark this as the solution by clicking the tick next to this answer. Marking this as the solution shows anyone else on the internet who finds this question that this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

touch /var/log/apache2/modsec_debug.log
chown apache_user:apache_user /var/log/apache2/modsec_debug.log

SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly  to 
SecAuditEngine On

Comment: I touched those files, now they exist and the ownership belongs to www-data. I also changed the configuration to be SecAuditEngine On, restarted Apache and then tried the same requests to my server (listed at the end of my original post). Then checked modsec_audit.log and modsec_debug.log in /var/log/apache2 unfortunately they are still empty :-(